# joining same table multiple times in t-sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am confused with joining same table multiple times
Fro ex: I got below tables

```
create table #cust (id int , name varchar(50) )
insert into  #cust values (111, 'john')
create table #addfrom (addid int , address varchar(50) )
insert into  #addfrom values (111, '11,st')
insert into  #addfrom values (111, '12,st')
insert into  #addfrom values (111, '13,st')
create table #reg (regid int , reg varchar(50) )
insert into  #reg values (111, 'nissan')
insert into  #reg values (111, 'hyhun')
insert into  #reg values (111, 'kia')
insert into  #reg values (111, 'bmw')
```

when I join individually:

```
select 
    c.*
from 
    #cust c join #addfrom a on c.id = a.addid
```

--3 rows

```
select 
    c.*
from 
    #cust c join #reg r on c.id = r.regid
```

--4 rows

But when I join like below:

```
select 
    c.*
from 
    #cust c 
    join #addfrom a on c.id = a.addid
    join #reg r on c.id = r.regid
```

I got 12 rows, but I am expecting 7 rows. how can I achive this???
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @TheGameiswar, thanks for reply. Yes but more records than expected.

Comment: why do you expect 7 rows? you join 1 with 3 with 4 rows ... so you get 1 * 3 * 4 = 12 joined rows

Comment: Your output has to be 1rows* 3rows*4rows which will be 12, What logic you are expecting to get 7 rows?

Comment: @PrfctByDsgn, In my second join 1*4???  `c.id = r.regid` is this mean will I get 4 rows?

Comment: @PrfctByDsgn, in this case if I want to get only 7 rows by joining 3 tables how can I get it?

Comment: Yes, that's what you said yourself.. Think about it, if 1 record should have be multiplied into 4, then 3 records (with the same logic of course) should be multiplied into 12 , unless a relation between second and third table is mentioned or in case they are `1..1` relations.

Comment: If you want 8 rows use union instead of join

Comment: Please post your output table

Comment: @Ashu, If I do that I am missing #reg information from first SELECT statement and also missing #addfrom information from second SELECT statement

Comment: I have posted my answer please comment on that what is missing in that answer

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```
select * from #cust c 
union
select * from    #addfrom a 
union
select * from     #reg r
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `UNION` of the two tables resulting from the joins

```
select 
    c.*, r.*
from 
    cust c
    join reg r on c.id = r.regid

UNION  

select 
    c.*, a.*
from 
    cust c 
    join addfrom a on c.id = a.addid
```

as long as the two tables have the same number of columns. You might need to define new columns (in the first and the second join) if you want to make sense of your data.